# How to determinate the scope of a test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

How i can determinate what is the best way of test a feature:

by example

I have a email validation that is made by a function that returns an object with errors, i should test this as a unit test and test this function or should create an e2e that test the ui show  the proper validation message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do both. Each of them tests different things.

In this case you should start with unit tests.

You want to get (quick) feedback from the test and testing the function directly is the best feedback you can get. If the tests fails you are pretty sure it is related to the function under test. With unit tests you can easily test all paths and error conditions of the function.

The e2e test checks that all the layers (which in the end call your function) work together. If it fails there could be an issue on any(!) layer. It would be more work to find the cause of the problem. That's why you do not test the details of the function from an e2e test. Why involve all the layers if you can check the function directly?

You then write more unit(!) tests on the ui side using stub data for you object. You don't call the function. Pass the stub data to the ui and check that it is handled correctly depending on the stub data. For example you could test the success case without error and another with error and so on.

Having done that you know that the function works and that the ui handles the result of the function.

Now you could write e2e tests.

If e2e tests make sense heavily depends on your context. In my experience that's a lot of work with little return. This may be different in your context. I fear you have to find out for yourself if it pays off :-)